# How to create a file with functions in C and access them from my application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, cgrect

I would like to "extend" `CGGeometry` but that is not a class. So I have to create external functions I can use from my App.

I have created a header file with a code like this:

```
#ifndef CGGeometry_Extensions_h
#define CGGeometry_Extensions_h


CGRect CGRectFromCenterAndSize(CGPoint center, CGSize size) {
  CGFloat width = [size width];    //1
  CGFloat height = [size height];  //2
  CGFloat x = center.x - width;
  CGFloat y = center.y - height;
  return CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
}

#endif /* CGGeometry_Extensions_h */
```

I have compiling errors on lines marked with `\\1` and `\\2`

> Bad Receiver type 'CGSize' (aka struct CGSize)

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these codes are syntax error in C:

```
  CGFloat width = [size width];    //1
  CGFloat height = [size height];  //2
```

I am not sure how `CGFloat` define, Will it should be

```
  CGFloat width = size.width    
  CGFloat height = size.height
```

Comment: The error message indicates that this is being compiled as ObjC; it's not a syntax error. It's a type problem.

Comment: i am not sure that there is a similar syntax like `CGFloat width = [size width] ;` in traditional C or not.. It looks radiculous.